# DateTimeZone works with PHP v7.0 but not with v5.4

Tags: php, php-7

While converting from one timezone to another the following codes works well with PHP v7.0(dev) but throws an error when executed in PHP v5.4. How can I make it compatible?

```
//---CODE------------------------------------------------------------
$time_object = new DateTime('2011-04-19 17:45', new DateTimeZone('+0530'));
$time_object->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$LondonDateTime = $time_object->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $LondonDateTime;
```

Error in PHP v5.4

```
//---ERROR WITH PHP v5.4--------------------------------------
DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone (+0530)
```

Comment: check http://php.net/DateTimeZone.listIdentifiers on both versions.

Comment: Note that "+5:30" *is* in fact a "bad" timezone. If at all possible you should avoid using it and use proper timezone identifiers like `Asia/Bangkok`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's down to [this PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45528), which was fixed in [PHP 5.5.10](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.5.10). You should be able to use this (admittedly quite ugly) workaround:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('O', '+05:30')->getTimezone();
```